# Pandas Line Plotting with Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, multi-index

After reshaping my dataset, I'm having some trouble trying to create my intended line plot.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diQ4q.png)

How can I create a subplot that looks like this the one below for each canton with a for loop ? (The x axis would be the years, the y axis would be the value of the tax rates and we would have multiple lines for each value of income and this ---> for each canton)

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXWK6.png)

Thanks !

```
taxrates_short.set_index("year")
taxrates_short.groupby(["canton","income"])["avg_tax_rate"].plot(ax=ax, x="year", xlabel="year", y="avg_tax_rate", ylabel="avg tax rate", legend=False)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

group the dataset by canton, then plot each canton on the graph

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create df ...

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

dk = df.groupBy('canton')
for cantonValue, groupedDF in dk:
  # plot groupedDF based on cantonValue
  groupedDF.plot(ax=ax, x="year", xlabel="year", y="avg_tax_rate", ylabel="avg tax rate", )
```

in order to get each group colored correctly, it'll be easier to use a different approach

```py
df.set_index("year", inplace=True)

df.groupby("cantonValue")["avg_tax_rate"].plot(legend=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer  but it doesn't look as good as expected: https://imgur.com/k4lNtrv

Comment: add more options to the groupdDF.plot command to make the plot look as intended. Year as x axis, and cantonValue as key

Comment: it begins to look better ---> I now have one graph for each canton. However, for a reason I ignore the lines of the graph look like they are connected/glued and I would like to avoid that : https://imgur.com/tJL0guN

Comment: can you include a code segment in the question for how you're adding each df to the plot

Comment: I have just added the code that allowed me to do the previous plot :)

Comment: I just need to find a way of "separating" those lines and finally give a different color for each income : https://imgur.com/SHrAYT9

Comment: @Lavokv my most recent edit uses pandas inherent plotting processes to do this. We can do it with my initial way, but that's like writing your own sort method instead of using the sort that already exists. the last code segment i included will plot each cantor groups tax rate with different colors and label the legend by their cantorValue. it should also fix the lines being connected

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it brings to something like this : https://imgur.com/u5QW4vA (I have replaced the first block code with the one that you added)

Comment: looks like it's because theres data groupings for income as well. the line's being "connected" are because it's graphing each income group for each cantonValue. if you want you can either plot just 1 income group by adding a bracket ['income' == 20000]. or by changing the group by parameter from "cantonValue" to ["cantonValue", "income"]

Comment: I've tried to group by ["canton", "income"], unfortunately it displays again all the canton values and all the different incomes on the same graph... Moreover, the x axis is not the years anymore... : https://imgur.com/St4HNyk (I have added the code that I used in the question box)

Comment: I have updated the appearance of the dataset in the question block